# Assign a relationship after loop in php

Tags: php, laravel

I want to loop over a collection of items and attach a relationship based on if a particular condition is satisfied. Here is my code

```
 public function bulkAssign()
{
    $trainers = MasterTrainer::all();
    for ($i=0; $i < count($trainers); $i++) {
        $this->assignToManager($trainers[$i]);
    }

    // return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Project Managers Assigned Successfully');
}

private function assignToManager($trainer)
{
    $manager = ProjectManager::where('state', $trainer->state)->first();
     return $trainer->update([
            'project_manager_id' => $manager->id
        ]);
}
```

What I get is it attaches only the first manager to all the elements in the collection. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Id use a foreach instead of that for loop, but on the surface, this "should" work. Are you getting any errors? Have you checked that `$trainers` contains all the records you expect and that they all have a `state`  value? Have you checked that the `ProjectManager` all have a `state` value and that they are the same as the trainers?

Comment: If `ProjectManager::where....` returns false, `$manager->id` would cause a null pointer exception and halt execution. So if the second trainer's state, doesnt match a project manager, that could be halting your script before it loops through all of the trainers

Comment: @WesleySmith i used a foreach loop and it's the same. I am not getting any errors. And All trainers have a state value as well as the project manager. That's the point i am not getting any errors. The script isn't halting. Just attached an the id of the first manager it gets to all the trainers

Comment: Can you use xdebug to set a breakpoint after `$manager = ProjectM......` and inspect $trainer and $manager?  The error seems to be in something outside the scope of this code.

Answer (score 0):

can you inline the func for now? do some sort of echo/debugging?

but also I see several issues:

1. yes do use foreach because that is a bit better and you avoid having to use $i (making code a little more easy to read)
2. you are not attaching a relationship, you are setting a project_manager_id (i say this because initially i automatically thought you were going to dynamically add a relationship to model)
3. without knowing your db schema.. could you not do some sort of trick to avoid having to do this nth times?

```
    $manager = ProjectManager::where('state', $trainer->state)->first();
```

you could either do:

```
$states = $trainers->pluck('states');
$managers = // do a query to get one trainer per state using group by

foreach ($trainers... ) {
  $manager = $managers->where('state', $trainers->state)->first() // this is collection not eloquent
  $trainer->update([
            'project_manager_id' => $manager->id
        ]);
```

other would be to create a scope where you do a sub query to get manager id when u query for trainers